# Having troubles with AMD import of cytoscape-context-menu "Uncaught TypeError: contextMenus is not a function"

Tags: javascript, requirejs, contextmenu, cytoscape.js

I am really new to programming and trying to load [cytoscape-context-menu](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-context-menus) extension. I followed the instructions on GitHub and tried this `test.js` code:

```
require(['cytoscape.js', 'cytoscape-context-menus.js', 'jquery.js'], function( cytoscape, contextMenus, jquery ){
  console.log(contextMenus);
  contextMenus( cytoscape, jquery );  // register extension
});
```

My `index.html` looks like this:

```
<script src="require.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

I have downloaded the latest versions of all the `.js` files and put them in the same dir as `index.html`. However during the debugging in Chrome `ContextMenus` is left `undefined` and I get this type of error:

```
test.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: contextMenus is not a function
    at test.js:3
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1696)
    at Module.check (require.js:883)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1139)
    at require.js:134
    at require.js:1189
    at each (require.js:59)
    at Module.emit (require.js:1188)
    at Module.check (require.js:938)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1176)
(anonymous) @   test.js:3
execCb  @   require.js:1696
check   @   require.js:883
(anonymous) @   require.js:1139
(anonymous) @   require.js:134
(anonymous) @   require.js:1189
each    @   require.js:59
emit    @   require.js:1188
check   @   require.js:938
enable  @   require.js:1176
init    @   require.js:788
callGetModule   @   require.js:1203
completeLoad    @   require.js:1590
onScriptLoad    @   require.js:1717
load (async)        
req.load    @   require.js:1942
load    @   require.js:1685
load    @   require.js:834
fetch   @   require.js:824
check   @   require.js:856
enable  @   require.js:1176
enable  @   require.js:1557
(anonymous) @   require.js:1161
(anonymous) @   require.js:134
each    @   require.js:59
enable  @   require.js:1113
init    @   require.js:788
(anonymous) @   require.js:1460
setTimeout (async)      
req.nextTick    @   require.js:1815
localRequire    @   require.js:1449
requirejs   @   require.js:1797
(anonymous) @   test.js:1
```

I already tried other extensions from iVis-at-Bilkent, like `cytoscape-popper`, `cytoscape-cose-bilkent` in exactly the same manner and it all worked. I looked through the problematic `cytoscape-context-menus.js` and saw it has this structure:

```
;(function(){ 'use strict';

  var $ = typeof jQuery === typeof undefined ? null : jQuery;

  var register = function( cytoscape, $ ){
  '' a lot of Code here ''
  }

  if( typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports ){ // expose as a commonjs module
    module.exports = register;
  }

  if( typeof define !== 'undefined' && define.amd ){ // expose as an amd/requirejs module
    define('cytoscape-context-menus', function(){
      return register;
    });
  }

  if( typeof cytoscape !== 'undefined' && $ ){ // expose to global cytoscape (i.e. window.cytoscape)
    register( cytoscape, $ );
  }

})();
```

It was totally different from the other extensions, for example `cytoscape-popper.js` starts with this:

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
    if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory(require("popper.js"));
    else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define(["popper.js"], factory);
    else if(typeof exports === 'object')
        exports["cytoscapePopper"] = factory(require("popper.js"));
    else
        root["cytoscapePopper"] = factory(root["Popper"]);
})(this, function(__WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_8__) { 
... A lot of code here
```

My idea was that it has something to do with different realisation for module exposure, however my current knowledge doesn't allow me to fix it. Sorry for long text but any suggestions would be much appreciated as I stuck with this for a few days.